# single line telnet commands using terminal

Tags: bash, command-line, telnet

I need to pull something along the lines of "telnet root@192.168.2.99: irinject BACK"
however this refuses to work. There is no password required.

What is the correct syntax to perform this task using the terminal on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: @abkai, no-password `root` access is a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must do it this way, use `echo` or etc. to pipe commands to the `telnet` session — and be ready to reinstall machines as they get hacked.

Strongly preferred is to use `ssh` with key access; you can even include the command that way.

```
ssh -i path/to/root-key root@host command
```

Comment: Thanks! You've peeked my interest, how would I set up ssh to use key access?

Comment: See for example http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/10/05/ssh-keygen-tutorial-generating-rsa-and-dsa-keys/ for generating keys.  You would in this case generate a single key, copy the *public* key into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on each machine, and keep the *private* key in a secure place (ideally on a separate secure machine).  Also make sure `sshd` is running on all target machines.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html for more information.